# Is it possible to change the directory where node.js modules are installed?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there any way to change the directory where node.js modules are installed? By default (on Linux Mint 13), `npm install express` installs the `express` module in `home/username/node_modules`, but I want modules to be installed by default in `home/username/Dropbox/node_modules` instead.

Comment: Was Just curious, why would you need that. If you want to share some common packages among different projects why not do global install.

Comment: @SushantGupta I'm using both Linux and Windows, and I need the modules to be synced with all my computers. That's why I want to keep the modules in the Dropbox folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you want to change installation directory try setting relevant [prefix](https://npmjs.org/doc/config.html#prefix).

Just a suggestion though, if its a small project, a quick fix is simply install packages separately on each machine. If its a big project then I guess you would be atleast using some source control like `git`. All package dependencies can be managed elegantly using source control.

Comment: See here also: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-Where-Does-Node-js-And-Require-Look-For-Modules-.htm